# Owl Carousel not displaying after being built with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Using an AJAX call I am getting the most recent videos posted to a vimeo account.  Then using jQuery I am looping through the data and building a set of divs that will function as a carousel of the most recent videos.  I am using Owl Carousel and have used it successfully in the past.

I know the AJAX call is returning the JSON data I need.  I know that my jQuery code is building the carousel components in the DOM.  My problem is that when I call the carousel it shows up blank in the browser window.  Using the developer tools I can see the divs are there and they have all the necessary mark-up that should allow Owl Carousel to do it's things.  What am I missing?  Is it an issue with using javascript to build the html elements for the carousel?

Here is a simple version of what I'm trying to build:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="owl.carousel.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="owl-carousel" id="vidCarousel">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/4462530/videos.json",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      pppVideos = data;
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var vid = pppVideos[i].url
        $('#vidCarousel').append('<div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a     class="owl-video" href="' + vid + '"></a></div>')
      }
     }
  });

  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        merge:true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        video:true,
        lazyLoad:true,
        center:true,
        responsive:{
            480:{
                items:2
            },
            600:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    })


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No, nothing showing in the console